# HTML 5 real time data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, real-time

Looking for a solution to draw an html table reflecting some server side data but somehow in real time. Some might suggest using a timer refreshing the table asynchronously, however this is not the solution in mind. 
In other words, what is needed is some sort of a push notification from the server each time a record is inserted into the table, to be reflected on screen.
My web application is built using ASP.net MVC 4.

Comment: how about SignalR http://signalr.net/

Comment: Please pick an answer to accept if any of these helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider [Server Sent Events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events), if you don't need bi-directional data back and forth from client to server.

Comment: Note that with SSE and MVC, your controller method cannot return a result, because that will close the connection; it has to [write directly to the Response object in some kind of loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35678190/111794), in order to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 Websockets are best for such things.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: EventSource is far easier to setup for this kind of use case.